# Prefix Expression Tree Recursion Prints unwanted symbols

Tags: java, recursion, prefix

```
private String prefix(ExpressionNode t){
    if (t.left==null && t.left==null){
        return Integer.toString(t.operand)+" ";
    }
    newLine+=t.operator+" ";
    newLine+=prefix(t.left)+" ";
    newLine+=prefix(t.right)+" ";
    return newLine;
}
```

This is the code I have to convert a binary tree into an expression in prefix order. The result gives unwanted symbols. What is wrong?
Input: "6 9 + 7 -" (already converted from postfix expression to binary tree)

Expected Output: - + 6 9 7

Actual Output: - - + 6  9 7

How to I get rid of the extra "-" symbol?

Comment: `newLine` isn't declared in this method, so it must be coming from a member variable somewhere. Make it a local variable.

Comment: but if you declare a local variable, isn't it revised every time you recurse the code?

Comment: No, it's only revised if the variable lives for longer than a single invocation of the method. [Try this](https://ideone.com/J7XETq) - try uncommenting line 16, which makes it a local variable. ([Here's one with a local variable](https://ideone.com/xtTgGE))

Comment: Ok it works now! Thank. As a follow up, how can I modify it to be a tail recursion (like use newLine as a part of the parameters)

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.
This problem is solved; your question on tail recursion is a separate issue (and too broad for SO).